# PHP - Cannot Connect To FTP Server

Tags: php, ftp

I can't get this to connect to the FTP server for some odd reason, can anyone help me? What it does is tell me that it could not connect to the ftp server.

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "serverip";
$ftp_port = "22";
$ftp_username = "vpslogin";
$ftp_userpass = "vpspassword";

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_port) or die("Could Not Connect To FTP Server: "$ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$server_file = "directoy/listing";

// open local file to write to
$local_file = "local.txt";
$fp = fopen($local_file,"w");

// download server file and save it to open local file
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $fp, $server_file, FTP_ASCII, 0))
  {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
  }

// close connection and file handler
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to ftp over ssh...port 22 is ssh. **Port 21 is FTP**

Comment: @Rafael Port 22 is sftp and SSH, no? Dailyinsanity, If you convert the port from a string to an INT does it work? If not you may need to try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php.

Comment: @chris85 That is the wrong advice, SSL is completely different alternative. The OP is confusing ftp_connect with ssh2_connect http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php Like I said already, **he needs to be on port 21 for his code to work.** http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php

Comment: @Rafael I access the ftp on port 22 (same as the SSH (it's on a debian machine)), but i figured out the problem, it was something to do with the account config on the machine.

Comment: @dailyinsanity That's just nonsense. Anyway, please delete your question or post your solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Port 21

*you also forgot concat on line 8*

---

```
<?php

# FTP Info
$ftp_server   = "serverip";
$ftp_username = "vpslogin";
$ftp_userpass = "vpspassword";

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could Not Connect To FTP Server: $ftp_server");

ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$server_file = "directoy/listing";

# Open Writable File
$local_file = "local.txt";
$fp = fopen($local_file,"w");

// download server file and save it to open local file
if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $fp, $server_file, FTP_ASCII, 0))
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
else
  echo "Error downloading $server_file.";

# Close all
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: i am trying to connect ftp, but getting error. and error id "Could Not Connect To FTP Server".  i am using same code with my conditional.